# check box detail view

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a situation where in I have detail row inside a table which has checkbox as select component

The behaviour I expect is

1)When I click on the detail row image the row should expand showing the detail of it's parent row but the checkbox should not be selected and the background colour of the parent row must be removed-**working fine**.

2)When the detail row is opened and I click on the checkbox the checkbox should get selected and the backgroung colour of the parent row should change **working fine**.

3)When detail row is open and checkbox is checked if I perform collapsing of the detail row the checkbox status should remain as it is and the background colour of the parent row must remain same **working fine**.

All the above scenario works fine when i select the first row

The problem is

When I select the second row the first row checkox status is retained but the background colour of the parent row is remove.
I'm using 
**$(row).siblings("selected").addClass("selected");**

In order to retain the background colour of the sibling row which were previously selected

But it's not working as expected please help

Thanks in

```
**framework**.table.prototype._details_link_renderer = function(cell_value, is_detail_open)
{
    var details_img_url = this._properties.details_open_img_url;
    if(is_detail_open)
    {
    details_img_url = this._properties.details_close_img_url;
    }
    var img = $(document.createElement("img")).attr("src", details_img_url).addClass("open_close_img");
    var link = $(document.createElement("a")).attr("href", "#noAnchor").attr("title", rdx.i18n.get_string("rdx.table_show_hide_title")).append(img).bind(rdx.events.CLICK, {ns_table: this}, function(event) {
        var row=$(this).parents("tr:eq(0)");
        var rowInd =$(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").index()/2;
        //var rowcount=$(row).index()+1;
        $(row).siblings(".selected").addClass("selected");
        event.data.ns_table._toggle_details_row($(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").index()/2);

        if(!$(event.data.ns_table._select_checkbox_array[rowInd]).is(':checked'))
        {
        $(row).toggleClass("selected");
        }
        if ($(event.data.ns_table._select_checkbox_array[rowInd]).is(':checked'))
       {
         $(row).addClass("selected") ;
         //$(row).siblings(".selected").addClass("selected");
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

I have my own defined framework

Comment: do you have a JSfiddle or a live example?

Comment: it's a live example..

Comment: Is `$(row).siblings("selected")` returning anything? Shouldn't that be `$(row).siblings(".selected")`? Also, can you show us what's happening in code please, e.g. in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: oops sorry its $(row).siblings(".selected") only..

Comment: so you're looking for cells with `selected` css class and then adding `selected` css class to them?

Comment: I want to retain the cells which are already checked and the background of those also.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `$(row).siblings(".selected").addClass("selected");` can be removed because it doesn't do anything: It selects the siblings of `$(row)` whose `class` attribute contains `selected`. `.addClass("selected");` *only adds the class if it isn't already there*.

So, you have two `if` statements before `event.stopPropagation();`. As far as I can see, they could be replaced by a much simpler `if`/`else`:

```
/* If the checkbox is checked, add class="selected", otherwise remove it. */
if($(event.data.ns_table._select_checkbox_array[rowInd]).is(':checked')) {
    $(row).addClass("selected") ;
} 
else {
    $(row).removeClass("selected");
}
```

Does that give you what you're after?

Comment: At present im not looking for code cleanup ,I need solution to my problem and this does not help :(

Comment: OK, can you put your code up on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (even if it's just mocked up HTML and CSS) so we can have a good look at it? It's hard to answer your question without being able to see what's going on.

(BTW I wasn't offering a code cleanup - just explaining why `(".selected").addClass("selected")` doesn't fix the problem)